# Is there a way to tell if I've previously visited a search result?

Tags: google-search

I use Google search to research online and I don't want to collect data from the same website more than once.

Is there a way that Google can indicate if I have previously visited a search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search results include  the date you last visited a site.

For example:

> You visited this page on 14/2/19

[image: sample search results]